# Why doesn't the nav2 controller plugin API have a method for failing?

Tags: microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have another question about the design choices of nav2. Specifically, I'm wondering why the controller plugins (`nav2_core::Controller`) don't have a mechanism for failure. Consider the following example as motivation.

Suppose we have a very forgiving progress checker (our robot is slow and unreliable and so we have a 10 second timer for it to raise an error) and suppose we have a simulator in our controller plugin that can detect problems. Then in the event that our robot detects a problem in simulation, we will have to wait an additional 10 seconds for the control server (`nav2_controller::ControllerServer`) to quit. This seems far too long since we were able to detect a problem in the controller plugin 10 seconds early.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374470/why-doesn%27t-the-nav2-controller-plugin-api-have-a-method-for-failing?/) by [programmer-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/67325/programmer-man/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2021-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They do, throw an exception https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_controller/src/nav2_controller.cpp#L335

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2021-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/67325/programmer-man/) on 2021-03-23**:
Thanks Steve, I didn't see the try and catch, I was just looking at the API.

PS. Thanks for all of your other answers as well!

**Comment by [programmer-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/67325/programmer-man/) on 2021-03-23**:
PS. Where should I be asking these questions? Here? Discourse? Or somewhere else? Thanks.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-03-23**:
Here is probably the right place

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-03-23**:
If this (and the others) are correct, can you mark the check mark on the left to get them off of the unanswered questions queue?